# google maps doesn't work when including android app as library in another

Tags: java, android, maps

So practically as the title suggested, I have made an android app where I'm including google maps services and I have got the key and it all went just fine.
Now I have made my app as a library and used it in another app, but the google maps show me a blank page with LogCat warning:

```
Failed to load map.  Could not contact Google servers.
```

What would cause this problem? Am I supposed to specify the new package in google API access? or something else would cause it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all go over the steps of this guide, and make sure that you have commited all the steps in it:

[Google Map API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Next, as far as I know this error can appear if you haven't produced the key the right way, you didn't register it correctly in the API Console, or you have some kind of permissions problem in your manifest file.

So take a look at this post as well on how to produce and register the key:

[Google Map API V2 Key](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the package name of the actual application in the google api console instead of the library package.